# Usage of QgsRuleBased3DRenderer with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, 3d, color, rule-based

I'm trying to use `QgsRuleBased3DRenderer` with PyQGIS in order to set different color in a 3D view.

I'm trying to make something similar to this but with the 3D syntax (here is the 3D syntax: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/3d/QgsRuleBased3DRenderer.html#qgis.3d.QgsRuleBased3DRenderer.Rule) but i don't get to it.

I found the example below only with 2D rule based here: [QGIS Rule Based Rendering](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140959/qgis-rule-based-rendering)

```py
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# define some rules: label, expression, color name, width
my_rules = (
    ('Feature one', '"type" LIKE \'first\'', 'green', 2),
    ('Feature two', '"type" LIKE \'second\'', 'red', 2),
    ('Feature three', '"type" LIKE \'third\'', 'blue', 2),
)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

# create a new rule-based renderer
symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2(symbol)

# get the "root" rule
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

for label, expression, color_name, width in my_rules:
    # create a clone (i.e. a copy) of the default rule
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    # set the label, expression and color
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color_name))
    rule.symbol().setWidth(width)
    # append the rule to the list of rules
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

# delete the default rule
root_rule.removeChildAt(0)

# apply the renderer to the layer
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

**UPDATE**

```
def create_material(ambient_color, diffuse_color=None, specular_color=None):
    """Create a material with the provided colors"""
    material = QgsPhongMaterialSettings()

    # Define ambient color
    material.setAmbient(ambient_color)

    # Define diffuse color
    if diffuse_color is not None:
        material.setDiffuse(diffuse_color)

    # Define specular color
    if specular_color is not None:
        material.setSpecular(specular_color)

    return material

#Here are just test rules
my_rules = (
    ('Feature one', '"type" LIKE \'first\'', False),
    ('Feature two', '"type" LIKE \'second\'', False),
    ('Feature three', '"type" LIKE \'third\'', False),
)

layer = iface.activeLayer()

# create a new rule-based renderer

color_2d = layer.renderer().symbol().color()
material = create_material(color_2d)
symbol = QgsPolygon3DSymbol()
symbol.setMaterial(material)
symbol.setEdgesEnabled(True)

renderer = QgsRuleBased3DRenderer
    
renderer.setSymbol(symbol)

# get the "root" rule
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()



for description, expression, IsElse in my_rules:
    # create a clone (i.e. a copy) of the default rule
    rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
    # set the label, expression and color
    rule.setDescription(description)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.setIsElse(IsElse)

    # append the rule to the list of rules
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)

# delete the default rule
root_rule.removeChildAt(0)

# apply the renderer to the layer
layer.setRenderer3D(renderer)

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Im now stuck with this. Seems symbol still not want to do the work. I get this error :

```
AttributeError: type object 'QgsRuleBased3DRenderer' has no attribute 'setSymbol'
```

but i see this attribute here ... https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/3d/QgsRuleBased3DRenderer.html#qgis.3d.QgsRuleBased3DRenderer

Comment: Maybe some other issues, but at least change your `renderer = QgsRuleBased3DRenderer` to `renderer = QgsRuleBased3DRenderer()` and it should not throw an error related to `setSymbol`

Comment: I get this error :`TypeError: QgsRuleBased3DRenderer(): not enough arguments` when i change to `renderer = QgsRuleBased3DRenderer()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANSWER**

I found this and it work for me

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
symbol = QgsPolygon3DSymbol()
material = QgsPhongMaterialSettings()

rulebase = QgsRuleBased3DRenderer.Rule(symbol)
rulebase.setActive(False)
renderer = QgsRuleBased3DRenderer(rulebase)
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()

def rule_based_style(layer, material, symbol, renderer, label, expression):
    
    material.setAmbient(QColor.fromRgb(50,50,250))
    symbol.setMaterial(material)
    symbol.setEdgesEnabled(True)
    
    
    rule = root_rule.clone()
    rule.setDescription(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    
    root_rule.appendChild(rule)
    rule.setActive(True)
    for child in rule.children():
        rule.removeChildAt(0)
    layer.setRenderer3D(renderer)
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())

#Then you can apply new rules:

rule_based_style(layer, material, symbol, renderer, 'test rules', ' \"Subbasin\" IN (2,4,6) ')
rule_based_style(layer, material, symbol, renderer, 'Something else', ' \"Subbasin\" IN (3,5,7) ')
rule_based_style(layer, material, symbol, renderer, 'Something else', ' \"Subbasin\" IN (3,5,7) ')
rule_based_style(layer, material, symbol, renderer, 'Something else', ' \"Subbasin\" IN (3,5,7) ')
```

Comment: Accept your own answer (PS: you can't do it now but in some days e.g 48h)

Comment: yes i will ! thanks for your help